# Maximum and minimum of a real valued function

Tags: functions

If a real valued function is defined in an open interval say (a,b) and it increases monotonously in it, then is it right to say that it has a minimum at 'a' and a maximum at 'b'?
 For example, consider (sin(x))^3  in (-π/2,π/2)

Comment: Yes, but only is the function if also defined at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What you can say in general is that $\inf_{(a,b)}f=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\sup_{(a,b)}f=\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f(x)$. These two limits always exist (they can be infinite). As Sam mentioned, you can replace "inf" by "min" and "sup" by "max" only if the function is defined on the closed interval.

Comment: Also note that the correct term is *monotonically*, not *monotonously*.

Answer (score 1):

The terms maximum and minimum imply that the function reaches those values within the interval of interest. Better wording would be supremum and infimum which are the least upper bound and greatest lower bound respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If monotonically increasing function $f$ also defined in $[a,b]$, Yes. Otherwise, No.